# How to use two or more queue driver in one project laravel v4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am working in laravel v4.2 project and I have different queus tasks that I want to perform. But now I want to perform this task by using two or more drivers fot this. For example I have an queue to send registration email and now I want to send email using redis server.

Second queue I have is to send push notifications to users for this I want to use database drive. So is it possible that use two or more queue drivers on one project.

Please educate me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just write another `QueueManager` extend it from the Base `QueueManager`

**Extend Your Base Queue Driver**

```
use Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\RedisConnector;
use Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager;

class RedisQueueManager extends QueueManager
{
    public function __construct(\Illuminate\Foundation\Application $app)
    {
        parent::__construct($app);

        $this->registerRedisConnector();
    }

    /**
     * Get the name of the default queue connection.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDefaultDriver()
    {
        return 'redis';
    }

    protected function registerRedisConnector()
    {
        $app = $this->app;

        $this->addConnector('redis', function () use ($app) {
            return new RedisConnector($app['redis']);
        });
    }
}
```

**Now create a service provider to access it through app**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Extensions\RedisQueueManager;

class RedisQueueServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bindShared('redis-queue', function ($app) {
            return new RedisQueueManager($app);
        });
    }
}
```

**Finally Register Your Service provider in `config/app.php` providers array.**

**And use it.**

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $default = app('queue');

    $redis = app('redis-queue');
});
```